# Angular redirection from iframe

Tags: angular, web, redirect, iframe

My web application (App1), developped on angular, is calling another web application (App2), to do some stuffs. After all stuff done, App2 is redirecting to App1.
But the redirection is doing inside the iframe, and then i have App1 with an iframe with App1 inside...
Do you have any solution for the redirection doing inside the iframe is doing for the main app ?

Comment: Are those 2 apps on the same domain?

Comment: no ! i'm calling a web app developped by another team, on a different domain

Comment: Right. I guess you can implement a frame-buster script on your side. Google for it and you’ll find how that can be done.